# Can't connect to Apple Time Capsule in home network using Home Plugs from Win 7 Machine

Tags: windows-7, time, powerline-networking

I have the following home network setup with subnet 255.255.255.0  but recently moved my time capsule to a different location when I added a third Home Plug and can no longer ping or map a network drive to it from the Windows 7 Machine.  However using Airport Utility on the Windows 7 machine I can manually configure the Time Capsule.

Using a Macbook on WIFI Network 1 or 2 - I can backup to the time capsule, so its accessible via both the router wifi network and the time capsule wifi network.

The Time Capsule is set to BRIDGE function - ie no NAT or DHCP server enabled.

Any bright sparks out there that can help diagnose the problem?

```
    Router (192.168.1.254) WIFI Network 1
       |
       |
       |---- Home Plug one


       |---- Home Plug Two
          |
          |---- Computer A Windows 7 (192.168.1.160)
          |
          |---- Printer (192.168.1.69)


       |---- Home Plug Three
          |
          |---- Apple Time Capsule (192.168.1.150) WIFI Network 2
               |---- Smart TV (192.168.1.70)
               |
               |---- Apple TV (192.168.1.4)
```

Comment: What does "moved my time capsule to a different Location" mean? Where was it before? Did the Network topology Change? Another question: does the apple time capsule filter netbios traffic, is there an Option to configure that?